# input mask not working with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I'm currently using Knockoutjs to handle bindings in a bootstrap modal.  Everything works fine, until I start to add an input-mask into the fields.  For example, I have:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="cardModal" tabindex="-3" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" >
<input class="form-control amountmask borderblack" data-val="true" value="11000.89" />
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

This works fine, it uses AutoNumeric.js, this is applied via JQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // masked edit for dollar amount
        $('.amountmask').autoNumeric('init');
    });
</script>
```

If I add Knockoutjs into the mix, having the modal use data-bind:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="cardModal" tabindex="-3" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="with: itemForEditing">
<input class="form-control amountmask borderblack" data-val="true" data-bind="value: Amount" />
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

The binding works fine, but the input-mask stops working.  Is there anyway around this?  If i remove the data-bind, the input mask works again, but I loose the binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to create a custom binding that takes care of applying the jQuery plugin to your input.

The Knocout doc: [Creating custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) is very clear on how to do this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.yourBindingName = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
    // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
    // and again whenever any observables/computeds that are accessed change
    // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
  }
};
```

As you can read in the comments, you have implement the method like this:

- init: apply the autoNumeric plugin. You can use `allBindings` here to access additional options for your plugin specified in the ko binding, i.e. the `data-bind` attribute.
- update: this will be invoked if the view model observable property associated to this element changes. You can decide what to do about it. Normally you use this method to directly update the input text. In your case, I suppose that autoNumeric offers some kind of functionality to update the input value applying the appropriate mask. That's what you shpuld do here.

Note that the original value binding does two things:

- on the init, it attaches to the input change event, so that, when the input value changes, it updates the bound observable value
- the update is called whenever the observable property changes, and it updates the input value (text) directly using the new value.

So, you must replace this behaviours as I've explained you. That's why it doesn't work side by side with your plugin. By the way, it's much easier than you can think making your own custom binding and using it.